# Zooming not taking into account centering to node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to refactor [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Tokker/mwm1sxhh/21/) of a collapsible tree to work in d3 v5. However, the zooming / centering functionality seems to have broken. If I click on a node to center on it, then zoom in / out, the zooming translates to the point where the previous zooming occurred, it doesn't take into account the `centerNode` function. This all seems to be working great in v4.
Vice versa, after zooming if i click on a node to center it, the translation starts from the last centering (now it is not taking the zooming translation into account)

```
let root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });

let baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
        .attr("width", viewerWidth)
        .attr("height", viewerHeight)
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .call(zoomListener);

let svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");

function zoom() {
        if(d3.event.transform !== null) {
            svgGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform );
        }
    }

// Function to center node when clicked
function centerNode(source) {
    t = d3.zoomTransform(baseSvg.node());
    x = -source.y0;
    y = -source.x0;
    x = x * t.k + viewerWidth / 2;
    y = y * t.k + viewerHeight / 2;
    d3.select('g').transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .call( zoomListener.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x,y).scale(t.k) );
    }

let zoomListener = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3])
    .on("zoom", zoom);

function click(d) {
        if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // click suppressed
        d = toggleChildren(d);
        update(d);
        centerNode(d);
    }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k8ebfvyo/3/

Comment: Please include the relevant code here so it is more easy to check

Comment: @rekiem87 sure, i've included it above.